# Why I fail to append data with tableappender called by Python API?

Tags: python, dolphindb, appender

I uploaded data using `tableAppender` provided by Python API. But without any error reported after calling the code, the data was not appended to the DolphinDB table. Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting steps:

step 1:

First, check the result of `tableAppender.append`. The return value represents how many data items have been appended.

step 2:

If the value is 0, it means no data has been appended. Check whether the appended data exceeds the partition range.

For example, I want to get the result as follows:

[image]

But the partitioning scheme is:

[image]

Data to be appended is out of the partition range, so the append task fails.